# Yahoo Pipes: Missing Filter Rules

Tags: filter, rss, yahoo-pipes

I am trying to build a simple RSS filter in Yahoo Pipes for the first time.I would like to filter by date.

I have a bunch of RSS feeds from a "fetch feed" data source and I connect them to a filter. I am now supposed to get a item.y:published.utime field in the Rules dropdown. However, it is not there: I do not have any of the item.y fields at all.

If I start by editing an example filter, these fields are there. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown lists include only the basic options as these are most commonly used by novices making simple pipes. Yahoo developers also left many options off the dropdown lists because some of them are quite long and would spoil the layout such as this example..  *item.y:published.day_ordinal_suffix*

If you want to use the special 'y' fields as sources of data then simply type them by hand into the *rules* box of the filter module using the keyboard device attached to your computer.